# Do I get same charging speed when I use a MacBook's usb port to charge my iPad?

Tags: ipad, charge

I like to use my MacBook Pro's usb port to charge my iPad, but do I get same charging speed as compared to using the included power adapter?

Answer (score 2):

From the [Apple iPad Charging Support Doc](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4060).

> The fastest way to charge your iPad is with the included 10W USB Power Adapter. Your iPad will also charge, though more slowly, when attached to a computer with a high-power USB port (many recent Mac computers) or with an iPhone Power Adapter. When attached to a computer via a standard USB port (most PCs or older Mac computers) iPad will charge, but only when it's in sleep mode.

Your 10W iPad charger (which is different to your iPhone / iPod charger) is the fastest way to charge your iPad. It is faster than your Mac or PC's USB port.